# bootstrap datetimepicker format fail

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

this script I am using, when I click input datepicker show up and everything looks normal until I select a date input has the result like below.

```
    function datetime(elem) {
        $(elem).datetimepicker({ format: 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm', autoclose: true, weekStart: 1, language: "tr" }).next().on(ace.click_event, function () {
            $(this).prev().focus();
        });
    }
```

**result :**
    We.00.yyyy 12:00

```
<td aria-describedby="grid-table_EndDate" title="01.01.2015 00:00" style="" role="gridcell">
     <input id="1_EndDate" class="editable" type="text" name="EndDate" style="width: 98%;" role="textbox">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strangely `DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm` solved the problem.